# Using the same iPhone app name as many other apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution

Does anyone know where I set my iPhone apps name?

When trying to determine what to call my iPhone app... I noticed that I can pick a name
that ALREADY has several apps called the same thing.

Why is that allowed?

http://tinypic.com/r/nygwso/3

Answer (score 0):

The name is set when you upload an new app on `https://itunesconnect.apple.com/`. In my experience, duplicated names were not allowed, there is a message like 'name already taken' when clicking the submit button. Maybe Apple relax the checking lately.

Comment: It's not allowed, but you can change it slightly or add something onto the end like "Split the Bill ~ Restaurant Edition" or "Split the Bill ~ College Roommate Edition"